# The conduction electrons in metals is a thermal phenomenon?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, thermoelectricity

When applying an external electric field in a metal at absolute zero, there is electrical current?

There must be thermal fluctuations in the electron's band to be occurs current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, there is a belief (though obviously not verifiable) by solid-state physicists that a metal cannot exist at absolute zero. The Fermi surface of the metal will be unstable to order of some sort such as superconductivity, charge density waves, magnetic ordering, etc.

With that said, let us concentrate on your scenario though. If there are no phonons to scatter the electrons at zero temperature and the sample is extremely pure (very few defects, impurities, etc.), then one would actually observe the phenomenon referred to as [Bloch oscillations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_oscillations). This is when you apply a DC electric field to a metal and you observe an AC current response due to the absence of scattering.

However, in the presence of impurities, I don't see why there couldn't be electrical conduction. There would still be a scattering mechanism, and the applied electric field would still be capable of causing the electrons near the Fermi surface to transition to a state right above the Fermi level.

Comment: Is there any chance of electrons excited by the electric field return to colder states emitting photons. I mean, if there is no thermal fluctuations, the quantum fluctuations of the electromagnetic vacuum start sucking energy of atoms!

In this scenario there would be no electric current.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "colder states", but I don't quite understand why the quantum fluctuations or the lack of thermal fluctuations matter. The electric field supplied would be on an energy scale much larger than these fluctuations, wouldn't it?

Comment: I refer to the paper of Dirac 1927 on emission and absorption of electromagnetic radiation. The system goes to the lower energy state emitting photons. 

[link](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/94746?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104479055667)

Answer (score 3):

In a metal the Fermi energy is somewhere in an unfilled band. At any temperature above absolute zero (which you can never reach) there are states available for electrons to get to and result in conduction at the Fermi surface. This will occur in any metal. Superconductivity is a separate phenomena that I won't touch on here.

Comment: I like your answer better than my own...

Comment: If the temperature is close to absolute zero, my relevant energy scale is much smaller. The continuous energy bands will begin to manifest discrete because this new scale. This is true? if not, why?
I mean, the number of ions core is more relevant when we approach to absolute zero, the limit N go to infinity is no more true.

Comment: I believe that this is well translated as: "Every conductor is a semiconductor or a superconductor at some sufficiently low temperature ?"

Comment: @Nogueira - Not at all!  There is a distinct difference to having the Fermi surface inside of a band - any (however small) perturbation will lift an electron into a position to conduct - the Fermi surface is, well, fuzzy.  This is quite different from a semiconductor.  And, not all materials are superconductors - that requires that a pairing mechanism (Cooper pair) or other bosonic quasi-particle be possible.

Comment: So the temperature don't have any relation to energy scale of the problem?

Comment: I belive that my doubts live in this idea: the conduction eletrons in metals are actually the thermas fluctuations in fermi level. So, this is wrong?

Comment: Within the band, essentially not - there is an unoccupied state just above the last occupied one.  Off hand I would guess the 'spacing' at something of the order of a few eV (width of the band) divided by the number of atoms in the sample (number contributing to the formation of the band).  So, really, really, ..., really small. (A really small number of atoms in the sample leads to other effects on the band structure).

Comment: but if the temperature is so low that KbT is the order of the spacing of energy levels?. The system is frozen!?
Can be some electric field of the other of Coulomb x Volt produce current in this temperature?

Comment: If you have a cubic centimeter sample, that has order a few times $10^{22} at/cm^3$, so the spacing is order $10^{-22} eV$, which is still 10 orders of magnitude below a picoKelvin, which has never been reached...

Comment: s there any chance of electrons excited by the electric field return to colder states emitting photons? I mean, if there is no thermal fluctuations, the quantum fluctuations of the electromagnetic vacuum start sucking energy of atoms! In this scenario there would be no electric current.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of superconductivity? This is a phenomenon where a material exhibits zero resistivity near absolute zero: it clearly contradicts your assertion that thermal excitation is needed for conductivity near absolute zero.

For a *semiconductor*, it is true that electrons need to be kicked into the conduction band by thermal fluctuations - but for a conductor, the electrons are already there - and they will move in response to an electric field at any temperature.

Comment: If the temperature is close to absolute zero, my relevant energy scale is much smaller. The continuous energy bands will begin to manifest discrete because this new scale. This is true? if not, why?

Comment: I mean, the number of ions core is more relevant when we approach to absolute zero, the limit N go to infinity is no more true.

Comment: In the case of superconductivity , we don't have anymore fermions, but instead,  we have bosons (cooper pairs). We lost the fermi level's discussion. i don't want speak about the possible strong photon-electron interactions when they approach to absolute zero.

Comment: I wrote wrong, is not photon-electron, but instead, phonon-electron.

Answer (score 0):

After going through number of articles for temperature reaching absolute zero, I find that it is difficult to attain absolute zero, which may mean that it is very difficult to stop interatomic movements or energy exchanges, and thus absolute zero is near theroretical. As far as superconductivity is concerned it must be a critical point, minimum energy transfer need and may reach no energy transfer at absolute zero temperature.